# kvm /sys/block/vdX/device/delete?

Tags: linux, kvm-virtualization

Why on kvm guest there is not file /sys/block/vdX/device/delete? maybe is like that because i can remove the drive from physical host?

I know i can attach and detach virtual disk to kvm guest using virtio driver disk in this following way, without reboot the vm

```
virsh attach-disk 3 /home/user01/vmdisk/LunMirror.img vde
virsh detach-disk 3 vde
```

How can i remove the virtual disk from the kvm guest?

Answer (score 2):

To remove a disk from a guest, you issue a detach command on the host. The guest doesn't control which hardware it gets, the admin of the host does.

Answer (score 2):

You do not need to do anything on the guest's side to hot unplug a disk. After running detach on the host it should disappear in the guest. If this does not work, make sure you have the   acpiphp and pci_hotplug kernel modules loaded.